# Cocoa bindings display 0 on pattern value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, binding

Right now, I have a label that is displaying the number of results found on a search operation. However, it doesn't display "0 Found" when there are no results, how can I make that happens?

The label only displayed when there is at least 1 found: "1 Found"

Thanks!

[Screenshot of parameters: display pattern value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veODU.png)

Comment: Is it possible that for that particular case the array is `nil`? Try setting the *Null Placeholder* in your binding to *0 Found*.

Comment: Remove the Hidden2 binding.